# Validation Rule if checkbox is checked then another field should not be equal to some value

Tags: apex, validation-rule

I have 2 objects

1. Timecard `pse__Timecard_Header__c` and
2. Period `c2g__codaPeriod__c`.

The relationship between these two objects is there is a lookup field `PD__c` which is related to Period.

There is a picklist field **Status** `pse__Status__c` on Timecard object with following values:

Saved

Submitted

Approved

Rejected

There is another checkbox field **Closed** `c2g__Closed__c` on Period Object. If this checkbox is checked then I want the status not to be equal to Rejected.

This is what I came up with but it is not working.

```
AND(Period__r.c2g__Closed__c == TRUE,
ISPICKVAL(pse__Status__c , "Rejected"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula should be:

```
PD__r.c2g_Closed__c && ISPICKVAL(pse_Status__c, "Rejected")
```

There is no lookup field Period__c in your object, it's called PD__c, which is PD__r when used in a reference in a formula.

Answer (score 0):

You just need one "equal to" symbol

```
AND(Period__r.c2g__Closed__c = TRUE,
ISPICKVAL(pse__Status__c , "Rejected"))
```

Comment: Still, it fails.

Comment: Which object are you creating the record on? Are you specifying the lookup value.

Comment: I am creating the validation rule on Timecard object. Specifying the lookup value PD__c ? nope.

Comment: Isn't the lookup field called `PD__c`?  In that case couldn't you do `PD__r.c2g__Closed__c && ISPICKVAL(pse__Status__c , 'Rejected')`